# Herkunft von "dieser Tage"

Tags: etymology, grammatical-case, time

> Dieser Tage muss er Geburtstag haben.

Es scheint, als ob der Ausdruck "[dieser Tage](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dieser#Bedeutung1c)" eine Genitivform wäre. Aber Zeitausdrücke basieren meist auf den Akkusativ (diesen Sommer, diese Nacht, usw.) Wie ist es dann gekommen, dass "dieser Tage" eine Ausnahme ist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In älterem Deutsch stehen Zeitangaben oft im Genitiv; es ist also keine Ausnahme, sondern altertümlich. Ein anderes Beispiel ist "eines Tages". Der Wechsel auf den Akkusativ erklärt sich vermutlich dadurch, dass der Genitiv in modernem Deutsch generell aus der Mode kommt.

Comment: Ich glaube, dass das bei ungefähren Zeitangaben üblicher war genitiv zu nemen, jedoch nicht bei genauen Zeitangaben (unteranderem da diese of präpositional vorkommen). "Eines Tages" vs "An jenem Tag"

Comment: Es gibt so etwas wie adverbiale Genitivformen. Ältere erstarrte Formen, die nicht mehr frei gebildet werden können. Ihre Entstehung ist mir nicht ganz klar. Im Lateinischen gibt es etwas Ähnliches, den Lokativ. Das ist ein Ortsadverb in Genitivform, z. B. Romae in Rom. Mir scheint, das war Roma+in, zu Romai, und dann Romae, also eine Form, die durch historischen Lautwandel zufällig formgleich mit einem Genitiv geworden ist.

Comment: @Matthaeus das glaube ich auch. "Eines Tages", "eines Nachts", "eines Morgens",... passen alle in dieses Schema.